# Best option - Stripping whitespace using Rails or JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, whitespace, stripping

Due to a bug on the application I am attempting to strip leading and trailing whitespace from any input. It is a ruby on rails application however I am not sure what approach to take. The main point is not how to achieve this but rather which is the better approach to take in terms of efficiency etc.

**JQuery**

With JQuery I can just add the following:

```
$("input, select").change(function()
{
  this.value=$(this).val().trim();
});
```

With Ruby I can always use strip. What would the best approach be? I believe JQuery as its simple and effective however I default to JQuery generally as my knowledge of Ruby Rails is limited.

Comment: you should use `trim` in the client side and in the server side you should use `strip` .

Comment: I understand that but what I am asking is which is the better approach and why is it the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the leading and trailing whitespaces you can use.

```
value.strip
```

Less code is better, in my opinion.

Comment: I mean to apply this globally to the site. Because jquery runs on any input change then I thought it would be more effective. If I was to use ruby how could i apply this globally and what would the advantage be?

Comment: I guess, in that case, the jQuery way seems good. It'll deal with all the entries globally rather than for each value. 

So in that case, you'll have less code with jQuery.

Comment: They jQuery way will deal with whitespaces before they are submitted (client-side). Ruby can't do that. So I would go with the jQuery way if you mean to use it on all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can try this as well:

```
value.lstrip.rstrip
```

This will remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I understand the options but what I am asking is which is the best approach for speed and functionality.

Comment: Both are good....If you have something to do where after removing the whitespaces you need to perform some operation, you can do  this in common lib in ROR and thus would be global for all...Its a server side thing..